# How to process value from keyvalue?

Tags: angular, typescript, object, web, frontend

I have an object from which  I get boolean "issues", I define it as a string and if true  want to display a checkmark, otherwise want to display a cross.

```
<ul *ngFor="let filtered of reposFiltered | keyvalue">
<li *ngIf="filtered.key=='issues' && filtered.value=='true'"> <i class="bi bi-check-lg"> </i> </li>
<li *ngIf="filtered.key=='issues' && filtered.value=='false'"> <i class="bi bi-x-lg"> </i> </li>
</ul>
```

Object:

```
description: "The personal website of Ben Balter. Built using Jekyll and GitHub Pages. See humans.txt for more infos."
html: "https://github.com/mojombo/benbalter.github.com"
issues: false
language: "CSS"
name: "benbalter.github.com"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Current output:
This field is completely missing from the list.

Desired output:
if true want to display a checkmark, otherwise want to display a cross.

Comment: please show us the object, the current output and the desired output

Comment: Changed and added what you said

Comment: the field value does not exist inside your current object so do you need to only refere with the field issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul *ngFor="let filter of filtered">
  <li *ngIf="filter.issues==true"> <i class="bi bi-check-lg"> </i> </li>
  <li *ngIf="filter.issues==false"> <i class="bi bi-x-lg"> </i> </li>
</ul>
```